# Declaring keys with similar names in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a newbee question. I am looking at this shema fnd cant get the poing of declaring a keys with similar names.

```
exports = module.exports = function(app, mongoose) {
  var accountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
      id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
      name: { type: String, default: '' }
    },
     isVerified: { type: String, default: '' },
     verificationToken: { type: String, default: '' },
    name: {
      first: { type: String, default: '' },
      middle: { type: String, default: '' },
      last: { type: String, default: '' },
      full: { type: String, default: '' }
    },
    company: { type: String, default: '' },
    phone: { type: String, default: '' },
    zip: { type: String, default: '' },
    status: {
      id: { type: String, ref: 'Status' },
      name: { type: String, default: '' },
      userCreated: {
        id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
        name: { type: String, default: '' },
        time: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
      }
    },
    statusLog: [mongoose.modelSchemas.StatusLog],
    notes: [mongoose.modelSchemas.Note],
    userCreated: {
      id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
      name: { type: String, default: '' },
      time: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
    },
    search: [String]
```

Let's say I have here a `user.name` and `status.name` keys, and `name` key itself has `name.first` ... `name.full` properties. How does mongoose knows which `name` to use? What is the best practice to declare keynames and what problems it can cause?

Comment: It seems like you're lacking a fundamental understanding of how JavaScript objects and keys work. account.name is different from account.user.name and account.status.name. Using the same property name is not an issue, as they are properties of completely different objects.

Comment: @AJ Funk Yes, basically i get it. But in here we also have  `user.name` and separate `name` with first, middle, last and full subkeys and they have to be properties of a same object, but declared separately instead of being declared as subproperties.